# get the rows which have null value from right table

Tags: mysql

how can i get the null value if not exist in the right

what i have is two table one is `contract_type`

```
ID  |   name    
    |
1   |   full-time
2   |   half-time
3   |   volunteer
4   |   freelancer
```

and the second table is the relation between `contract_type` and employee
the name of the table is `contract`

```
ID  |      employee_id   |  contract_type_id  
    |                    |   
1   |          31         |       1
2   |          31         |       2    
3   |          31         |       4    
4   |          45         |       3
```

now i need the result to be the same as `contract_type` table is  with a new columns if exist from right or not

I tried this

```
select * from contract_type left join `contract` on contract_type.ID  = contract.contract_type_id  where employee_id   = 31
```

the problem now is the result is only three record but i expect to get at least something like

```
ID  |      name        |  contract_type_id  
    |                  |   
1   |     full-time    |       31
2   |     half-time    |       31         
3   |     volunteer    |       null
4   |     freelancer   |       31
```

or maybe

```
ID  |      name        |       status
    |                  |   
1   |     full-time    |       true
2   |     half-time    |       true
3   |     volunteer    |       false
4   |     freelancer   |       true
```

Comment: To fix your query, just move that condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.  What's happening is the conditional check in the `WHERE` clause: `contract.employee_id = 31` will exclude any rows that have a `NULL` value for `employee_id`. And that effectively negates the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN. Think of it this way: when the outer join doesn't find a matching row, MySQL basically "invents" a row to match, so the join operation can be satisfied, and row can be returned. And that invented row consists entirely of NULL values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your ID check into the `JOIN` criteria instead of the `WHERE`:

```
select *
  from contract_type
  left join `contract` on contract_type.ID  = contract.contract_type_id
   and employee_id = 31;
```

Comment: that's right , you got the trick and i didnt think about this  , thank you so much